# Perl command not giving expected output

Tags: perl

**Command:**

```
perl -lpe '1 while (s/(^|\s)(0\d*)(\s|$)/$1"$2"$3/)' test5
```

**Input:**

> 1234      012345               0
>
> 0.000             01234     0
>
> 01/02/03          5467        0abc
>
> 01234           0123
>
> 0000           000054
>
> 0asdf           0we23-1

**Current Output:**

```
perl -lpe '1 while (s/(^|\s)(0\d*)(\s|$)/$1"$2"$3/)' test5
```

> 1234      "012345"            "0"
>
> 0.000             "01234"     "0"
>
> 01/02/03          5467       "0abc"
>
> "01234"           "0123"
>
> "0000"           "000054"
>
> 0asdf           0we23-1

**Excepted Output:**

> 1234      "012345"              0
>
> 0.000             "01234"       0
>
> 01/02/03          5467        "0abc"
>
> "01234"           "0123"
>
> "0000"           "000054"
>
> "0asdf"           "0we23-1"

**Conditions to follow in output:**

1. All strings starting with 0 having alphanumeric character except / and . should be double quoted.
2. if string starting with 0 have only 0 character should not be quoted.
3. Spacing between strings should be preserved.

Comment: What's the `1 while` for? And why are you trying to make a single magic regex here, when it's much simpler to unroll the problem

Comment: How is (for example) "0we23-1" ending up quoted when your pattern has `(0\d*)` picking up the strings?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my @fields = split;
   s/^(0[^\.\/]+)$/"$1"/ for @fields;
   print join " ", @fields, "\n";
}

__DATA__
1234 012345 0
0.000 01234 0
01/02/03 5467 0abc
01234 0123
0000 000054
0asdf 0we23-1
```

Note - it doesn't strictly preserve whitespace like you asked though - it just removes it and reinserts a single space. That seems to meet your spec, but you could instead:

```
my @fields = split /(\s+)/;
```

as this would capture the spaces too.

```
join "", @fields;
```

This is reducible to a one liner using `-a` for autosplitting:

```
perl -lane 's/^(0[^\.\/]+)$/"$1"/ for @F; print join " ", @F'
```

If you wanted to do the second bit (preserving whitespace strictly) then you'd need to drop the `-a` and use `split` yourself.

Comment: your solution works absolutely fine in my scenario. Just one thing how can we pass the variable or data  from any text file instead of scalar value <DATA>

Comment: Use `<>` instead, and it'll read STDIN or file on command line - the same way as `grep`/`sed`/`awk` function.